# Putting /etc under source control

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bazaar, etc

I would like to put my /etc directory iunder source control using bazaar.

Are there any gotchas in doing this. It seems safer to do it user  an ordinary user rather than root - might there a be a problem with .bzr belonging to such a user.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should look at using [etckeeper](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/etckeeper/), instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Looks promising, I had to google to findo ut how to use it . Is there a pointer to a guide to setting it up.

Comment: I haven't used it personally, sorry. See if anything here helps: http://serverfault.com/search?q=etckeeper

Comment: `etckeeper` is awesome.  Two gotchas tho:  for backup, you end up pushing the repo somewhere remote.  Please use key-based SSH for that, so it gets done securely.  Also, what you store in `/etc` can be sensitive (think `/etc/shadow` or any private keys) so make sure that whereever you push the repo to does not have a 'public' webpage, or is being served out through any other unauthenticated means.

Answer (score 4):

Could be overkill for a single system (unless you need to 'rebuild' it from time to time) but the usual solution for [configuration management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management) is to use some [scm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) like [cfEngine](http://www.cfengine.org/), [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/), [bcfg2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcfg2) , or the like, and then put *their* data under source control.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way [using SVN and cron to manage /etc](http://lisas.de/~adrian/?p=478).  I suppose it could be adapted.